# passing parameter values from view to controller action method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a dropdownlist in my form, when the user changes the dropdownlist i want to send a 2 values from the view to the controller action method from the url.. with the below method im able to send 1 value, but how can i assign another value to the script..i want to assign continentId also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { $('#CountryId').change(function () { window.parent.location.href = "CountryCategory?countryId=" + $('#CountryId').val(); }); });
</script>

public actionresult CountryCategory(string countryId,string continentId)
{
}
```

my action method needs two parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var countryId = $('#CountryId').val();
var continentId= $('#ContinentId').val();

window.location.replace("CountryCategory?CountryId=" + countryId + "&ContinentId=" + continentId+ "");
```

why not $.post() ?

```
 $.post("CountryCategory",{CountryId : countryId,ContinentId : continentId},function(result){
    //receive data
      alert(result);
  });
```

Comment: thnku dis worked, what is $.post() ?...is there any other better way to do this than the way im doing?

Comment: Yes @sebastian $.post is Ajax support provided by jQuery, that means if you want to send or receive data from the server without page refresh. please refer http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming `continentId` value is belong from  `ContinentId`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { 
        $('#CountryId').change(function () { 
            window.parent.location.href = "CountryCategory?countryId=" + $('#CountryId').val();+"&continentId=" + $('#ContinentId').val();
        });
    });
</script>

public actionresult CountryCategory(string countryId,string continentId)
{
}
```

Comment: there is no error but its passing null value to the controller action for continentId ....but i tried the alert message in the script im getting the value correct for continentId  but its not being passed to the action method

Comment: i tried the same thing with +, for this only the value is null in the action method

Comment: @sebastian please check with alert and check URL having the `continentId ` value or not